# Emgu C# OpenCV: Make Color Black transparent

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, alpha

I'm currently trying to implement a function with OpenCV which makes the color black of an image transparent. I used this [thread](http://answers.opencv.org/question/24463/how-to-remove-black-background-from-grabcut-output-image-in-opencv-android/?comment=24786#comment-24786) as a guideline.
Currently it is not working and I'm not sure if it is because of my transfer to C# or another mistake.

```
public Image<Bgr, Byte> BlackTransparent(Image<Bgr, Byte> image)
        {
            Mat imageMat = image.Mat;
            Mat finalMat = new Mat(imageMat.Rows, imageMat.Cols, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv8U, 4);
            Mat tmp = new Mat(imageMat.Rows, imageMat.Cols, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv8U, 1);
            Mat alpha = new Mat(imageMat.Rows, imageMat.Cols, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv8U, 1);

            CvInvoke.CvtColor(imageMat, tmp, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
            CvInvoke.Threshold(tmp, alpha, 100, 255, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ThresholdType.Binary);

      
            VectorOfMat rgb = new VectorOfMat(3);

            CvInvoke.Split(imageMat, rgb);
           
            Mat[] rgba = { rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], alpha };

            VectorOfMat vector = new VectorOfMat(rgba);

            CvInvoke.Merge(vector, finalMat);
                
            return finalMat.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
        }
```

If anybody has an idea or suggestion I would appreciate it.

Bruno

Comment: Define "not working". | Two fairly obvious mistakes are that `tmp` and `alpha` are created as 4 channel, yet `tmp` is used to hold the result of conversion to grayscale (1 channel only), and `alpha` is meant to have the transparency channel (again 1 channel only). This might not cause issues, but it's misleading and wasteful anyway.

Comment: The function returns the same image which it recieves as argument. But thank you for the tipp with the channels ... I will change that

Comment: Ah, just noticed another thing: since you're adding transparency, shouldn't the return type be something like `Image<Bgra, Byte>` (BGRA rather than BGR colorspace) ?

Comment: This was the problem ... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public Image<Bgra, Byte> BlackTransparent(Image<Bgr, Byte> image)
        {
            Mat imageMat = image.Mat;
            Mat finalMat = new Mat(imageMat.Rows, imageMat.Cols, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv8U, 4);
            Mat tmp = new Mat(imageMat.Rows, imageMat.Cols, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv8U, 1);
            Mat alpha = new Mat(imageMat.Rows, imageMat.Cols, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv8U, 1);

            CvInvoke.CvtColor(imageMat, tmp, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
            CvInvoke.Threshold(tmp, alpha, 100, 255, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ThresholdType.Binary);


            VectorOfMat rgb = new VectorOfMat(3);

            CvInvoke.Split(imageMat, rgb);

            Mat[] rgba = { rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], alpha };

            VectorOfMat vector = new VectorOfMat(rgba);

            CvInvoke.Merge(vector, finalMat);

            return finalMat.ToImage<Bgra, Byte>();
        }
```

The return type of the function was wrong ... instead of the bgr colorspace it should be the bgra colorspace

Comment: how can I set the not full transparent like transparency to some level, semi transparent